# Collapsing toolbar with TabLayout not showing Toolbar

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to make collapsing toolbar with TabLayout as follows

https://i.stack.imgur.com/76m5h.gif

but my result is like this [image: check image]

as you can see the toolbar is not showing at all. 
in java I am setting toolbar as actionbar using

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

I tried many so answers and other sites but not able to solve my problem.

below is the xml I am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bg_main"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.gigamole.navigationtabstrip.NavigationTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/nts_strip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:nts_active_color="@color/white"
            app:nts_animation_duration="300"
            app:nts_color="@color/white"
            app:nts_corners_radius="1.5dp"
            app:nts_inactive_color="@color/white_transparent"
            app:nts_titles="@array/nts_titles" />


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager_photos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white_transparent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

here is the `styles.xml`

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Did you initialize the `Toolbar` on the java side? What are your `Styles.xml `codes?

Comment: That's weird, Can you try the `Layout` without the `NavigationTabStrip` and no `LinearLayout`, Just a `ViewPager` and let me know ?

Comment: @Mohsen the issue is toolbar is not visible why are you suggesting to remove linear layout?? Can you provide a valid reason??

Comment: @SaravInfern - Sure thing, Perhaps there is something that causes the `Toolbar` not showing by `LinearLayout` or expecially that Library `com.gigamole.navigationtabstrip.NavigationTabStrip`, Because as you can see, Everything(everycodes) seems to be ok! we need to check if Toolbar is showing without them or not! Got it?

Comment: That is why i suggested to create tabbed activity from default activity gallery, you downvoted me :(

Comment: @SaravInfern - The question is something else, You were trying to suggest something else !! Come-on, Have you seen the SO rules when posting an answer?

Comment: @Mohsen I have. Have you If not please [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the link, also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) will be useful to you

Comment: @Mohsen did but showing something like this now.http://tinypic.com/r/3494fpz/9

Comment: @KaranMer please try my suggestion or Srinivas Keerthiprakasam's suggestion from below

Comment: @SaravInfern your suggestion includes using default tablayout instead of which i am using third party library and srinivas's answer doesn't include collapsing toolbar.

Comment: @KaranMer you can include coordinator layout in the xml ,as @ Srinivas has not included the complete code of the xml

Comment: @KaranMer - Alright so, Adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` should solve the problem i guess...As @GPack said.

Answer (score 1):

CoordinatorLayout is a FrameLayout, thus the last view in order overlaps the first ones.
Add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to LinearLayout to anchor it to the bottom of AppBarLayout.

Answer (score -2):

you can do this with default android tabbed activity from gallery. For this right clickon package where you want to create->click on new navigate to gallery->choose `Tabbed activity` -> in the window choose Navigation style as `Action bar tabs(with viewpager)`

Comment: That's not what OP was looking for though!

Comment: @Mohsen what the OP is looking for please provide the correct solution